# Testing Marketing vehicle effectiveness

Tags: ab-test, hypothesis-testing, marketing, t

I have a set of customers who have been targetted using a marketing vehicle. Now i want to estimate if the marketing vehicle resulted in a better conversion (did they buy after that or not).
Currently, im taking a simple approach, where i check the conversion% (number of buyers/ total accts) for the target customers vs non-target customers.
But i would like to take a statistical approach to this, can you suggest some methods to measure this

Comment: How about a proportion test? A chi-square test could also be possible, maybe.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may conduct significance test for conversion percentage of target buyers. Here, t-test is preferable.